# Generically multiply values of different type in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Say I want to write a generic function that takes some value of type `K` and commutatively multiply it with an `f64`. The following works:

```rust
fn generic1<K>(a: K, b: f64) -> K
where
    K: Mul<f64, Output = K> + Add<K, Output = K> + Copy,
    f64: Mul<K, Output = K>,
{
     a * b + b * a
}
```

However, I am now no longer able to e.g. multiply two floats within the same function. Effectively, it seems like the bound `f64: Mul<K, Output = K>` is overriding/hiding (?) the impl `impl Mul<f64> for f64`. Here is an example:

```rust
fn generic2<K>(a: K, b: f64) -> K
where
    K: Mul<f64, Output = K> + Add<K, Output = K> + Add<f64, Output = K> + Copy,
    f64: Mul<K, Output = K>,
{
     a * b + b * a + b * b
}
```

which gives the following compiler error:

```
   |
16 |      a * b + b * a + b * b
   |                          ^ expected type parameter, found f64
   |
   = note: expected type `K`
              found type `f64`
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=055b78748d6d26248ba495c2e96f5b0d)), i.e. `f64 * <whatever>` now only works for `<whatever>` being of type `K`.

As a workaround, I can use the fully qualified syntax `<f64 as Mul<f64>>::mul(b, b)`, but that is extremely ugly. It feels like the compiler should be able to see that it can use an output of type `f64` and hence use the implementation of `f64 * f64` instead of `f64 * K`.

A less abstract example for what I want to do: `K` could be a vector type, or a scalar type, and I want to be able to do commutative scalar multiplication with it in a generic way.

What's going on here? Why can I no longer multiply `b * b`?

**Update**: @Ömer-erden noticed that it works when explicitly specifying `f64: Mul<f64, Output = f64>` as well. Unfortunately that workaround breaks when importing the [`alga` crate](https://crates.io/crates/alga) - see the [updated playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d787f2fef2cb935da78fad6b93ae319).

I'm not exactly sure what alga does to break the already weird behavior. As Ömer already noted, it looks like this is more of a bug or limitation of the type checker rather than a bug in alga/whatever, since ideally no code should be able to break resolution of `impl Mul<f64, Output = f64>` or similar for any builtin type.

Comment: It is not related with `alga`, it happens because of  `num_complex`, which is a dependency for `alga`, please see this [implementation](https://github.com/rust-num/num-complex/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L1011), i assume, this implementation makes things ambiguous again (f64 is applying this macro), here is i've reproduced the behavior without crate : [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50924bf4e2a43ed3bb763fb99efa88ba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a constraint which tells that when `K` is a right operand, you can multiply `f64` with `K`, and the output will be `K`. Also tells `f64` must implement `Mul<K, Output = K>`

```rust
f64: Mul<K, Output = K>,
```

I don't know yet, this might happen because of limited power of type-checker or bug but somehow implementation of `Mul<f64, Output = f64>` on `f64` becomes ambiguous because of the constraint `Mul<K, Output = K>`.

if you explicitly state the expected behavior which is `Mul<f64, Output = f64>` in your case :

```rust
fn generic2<K>(a: K, b: f64) -> K
where
    K: Mul<f64, Output = K> + Add<K, Output = K> + Add<f64, Output = K> + Copy,
    f64: Mul<K, Output = K> + Mul<f64, Output = f64>,
{
    a * b + b * a + b * b
}
```

it will work as expected.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3143908390baa0c03629aaa334dc5fe3)

Comment: This is rather surprising. I mean, `f64` is a concrete type, so the compiler knows its traits. And we still can call standard multiplication using `Mul::<f64>::mul(b, b)`, so the compiler still knows that this is possible. It just isn't _inferred_ anymore as an option.

Comment: @SvenMarnach you are right, this should constraint the `K` not `f64`, updated the post to not mislead